# Как в sqlite сделать запрос, чтобы из полного ФИО получить сокращенное?

Tags: python, sqlite, telegram-bot

Как в sqlite сделать запрос, чтобы из полного ФИО (фамилия, имя и отчество) получить на выходе сокращенное ФИО (фамилию и инициалы)?

В ячейке t_name указано полное ФИО (фамилия, имя и отчество)

Функция

```
conn = sqlite3.connect(settings.DATA_BASE)
cursor = conn.cursor()   
sql = f"""SELECT data, para, idgroup, subj_name, t_name, t_aud
         FROM subs 
         WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', data) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now', 'localtime') AND lower(t_name) like ? 
         ORDER BY para ASC"""
query = "%{}%".format(message.text.casefold())
query = query.title()
cursor.execute(sql, (query,))
result = cursor.fetchall()
if not result:
    msg = f"Не має замін для <b>{message.text}</b>."
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, msg, reply_markup=teacher, parse_mode='HTML')
    return
else:
    for ln in result:
        msg = f" Лента:   {ln[1]}\n" \
              f" Группа:   {ln[2]}\n" \
              f" Предмет:   {ln[3]}\n" \
              f" Преподаватель:   {ln[4]}\n" \
              f" Кабинет:  {ln[5]}\n"
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, msg, reply_markup=teacher, parse_mode='HTML')
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Смысл вообще сохранять три разных значения в одном поле?

Comment: @MyZik Есть нюансы, к примеру однофамильцы (3 шт.) , при поиске по фамилии он выдаст информацию по всем трем, а если фамилия + имя то он выдаст по одному инфу

Comment: Прямо классикой повеяло https://habr.com/ru/post/146901/

Comment: @Last_Arkhangel а вы вообще SQL знаете?

Comment: Ну так вы сами и ответили на свой вопрос, сохраняйте три поля в БД, и делайте выборку по фамилии + имени + отчеству. И показывайте в Вашей программе в любом удобном Вам виде

Comment: @MyZik Сделал такой запрос `SELECT SUBSTR(t_name, 1, MIN(10, INSTR(t_name, " ")-1)) as f, SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(t_name, " ")+1, 1) as l, FROM subs;` Первых два слова я разобрался как отделить, не могу понять (разобраться) как отделить 3 слово (отчество)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такой в итоге получился запрос

```
sql = f"""SELECT data, para, idgroup, subj_name,
    SUBSTR(t_name, 1, INSTR(t_name, ' ')-1) as f_name,
    SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(t_name, ' ')+1,1) as l_name,
    SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(SUBSTR(t_name, INSTR(t_name, ' ')+1), ' ')+ INSTR(t_name, ' ')+1,1) as o_name,
    t_aud
FROM subs 
WHERE strftime('%Y-%m-%d', data) = strftime('%Y-%m-%d', 'now', 'localtime') AND lower(t_name) like ? 
ORDER BY para ASC"""
```

Если в строке находится 2 (два) ФИО, то он только работает с одним ФИО (с первым)